# Couldn't remove mssql-server on linux

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

To work with ASP.Net I have wanted to install mssql-server. Unfortunately after at the end of installation, it should some error. So, I wanted to remove this bad installation to try to reinstall again. But when I tried to remove mssql-server by `sudo apt-get remove mssql-server` it showed the error below:

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
dpkg: error processing package mssql-server (--remove):
 installed mssql-server package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mssql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: This sounds like a question for [ubuntu.se] or [unix.se]. I assume the former, due to the use of `apt` and Suse and Redhat use different application managers (`zypper` and `yum` respectively).